# RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0 for Sequential of DINO model

Tags: python, pytorch

I’m getting the runtime error when trying to Sequentialise my linear layer with a DINO backbone from torch.hub.

```
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist

class LinearClassifier(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, num_labels=1000):
        super(LinearClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.num_labels = num_labels
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(dim, num_labels)
        self.linear.weight.data.normal_(mean=0.0, std=0.01)
        self.linear.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, x):
        # flatten
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)

        # linear layer
        return self.linear(x)


dist.init_process_group('gloo', init_method='file:///tmp/somefile', rank=0, world_size=1)
# load backbone
model = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/dino:main', 'dino_vits8')

#Setup linear layer
linear_classifier = LinearClassifier(1536, 1000)
linear_classifier = linear_classifier.cuda()
linear_classifier = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(linear_classifier)
state_dict = torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url(url="https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/dino/dino_deitsmall8_pretrain/dino_deitsmall8_linearweights.pth")['state_dict']
linear_classifier.load_state_dict(state_dict, strict=True)

#Sequentialise
model = torch.nn.Sequential(model,
                            linear_classifier)

x = torch.ones((1, 3, 224, 224))
out = model(x)
print("out: " + out)
```

Here is the print of the last layers of my sequentialised model:
[last layers printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkOlZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It loos lke the output of the `model(x)` (as defined by `model = torch.hub...`) has shape `1 x 384`, but your `linear_classifier` expects something of shape `_ x 1536` which is why you'll get this error. So you can just adjust that number of inputs by setting

```
linear_classifier = LinearClassifier(384, 1000)
```

Comment: I tried that first but then I got the error:
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DistributedDataParallel:
        size mismatch for module.linear.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000, 1536]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1000, 384]).

It appears that in Facebooks Evaluation code they transform the output of the backbone somehow: https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino/blob/cb711401860da580817918b9167ed73e3eef3dcf/eval_linear.py#L206